# Ember.js tutorial: error while loading route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am following the [Ember.js Todo tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/) but, instead of using the versions recommended in the tutorial, I am using the most recent ones, since I believe it's preferable to use the newest versions of available libraries. However, when I try to use fixtures to fill in the data, I am getting the following error:

```
"DEBUG: -------------------------------"
"DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0"
"DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88"
"DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0"
"DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0"
"DEBUG: -------------------------------"
"Attempting URL transition to /"
"Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook"
"Transition #0: application: calling deserialize hook"
"Transition #0: application: calling afterModel hook"
"Transition #0: todos: calling beforeModel hook"
"Transition #0: todos: calling deserialize hook"
"Error while loading route: Ember.Error@file:///C:/Projects/EmberTest/EmberTest/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js:910
Store<.modelFor@file:///C:/Projects/EmberTest/EmberTest/js/libs/ember-data.js:9805
Store<.findAll@file:///C:/Projects/EmberTest/EmberTest/js/libs/ember-data.js:9404
Store<.find@file:///C:/Projects/EmberTest/EmberTest/js/libs/ember-data.js:9073
Todos.TodosRoute<.model@file:///C:/Projects/EmberTest/EmberTest/js/router.js:9
/* stack trace goes on... */
```

Here are my application.js:

```
var Todos = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

router.js, which seems to be the culprit (the error is happening when calling this.store.find('todo'):

```
Todos.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('todos', {
        path : '/'
    });
});

Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return this.store.find('todo');
    }
});
```

And finally, my todo.js:

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title : DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted : DS.attr('boolean')
});

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [ {
    id : 1,
    title : 'Learn Ember.js',
    isCompleted : true
}, {
    id : 2,
    title : '...',
    isCompleted : false
}, {
    id : 3,
    title : 'Profit!',
    isCompleted : false
} ];
```

Has anyone have any idea about what might be causing this error?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am doing the *exact* same code, and it appears that `Todos.ApplicationAdapter` is not using the FixtureAdapter, but I don't know if that is true or not.